# Update complex entity in db

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I am working with facebook RTU and get json updates on the payments of my application`s users.
To have a better customer service i want to save all the json string facebook sends me , but in an ordered way.

For example,
I am getting this json:

```
{
  "id": "3603105474213890",
  "user": {
    "name": "Daniel Schultz",
    "id": "221159"
  },
  "application": {
    "name": "Friend Smash",
    "namespace": "friendsmashsample",
    "id": "241431489326925"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "charge",
      "status": "completed",
      "currency": "USD",
      "amount": "0.99",
      "time_created": "2013-03-22T21:18:54+0000",
      "time_updated": "2013-03-22T21:18:55+0000"
    }
  ],
  "refundable_amount": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "amount": "0.99"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "IN_APP_PURCHASE",
      "product": "http://www.friendsmash.com/og/friend_smash_bomb.html",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
  "country": "US",
  "created_time": "2013-03-22T21:18:54+0000",
  "payout_foreign_exchange_rate": 1,
  "disputes": [
    {
      "user_comment": "I didn't receive my item! I want a refund, please!",
      "time_created": "2013-03-24T18:21:02+0000",
      "user_email": "email\u0040domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want to save it in db but not as a string, as an object this style and also have the option to query by field value from my db.

```
        public class PaymentDetailsDto
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public PaidUserDto user { get; set; }
            public PaidApplicationDto application { get; set; }
            public List<PaymentActionDto> actions { get; set; }
            public RefundableAmountDto refundable_amount { get; set; }
            public List<PaymentItemDto> items { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string created_time { get; set; }
            public int test { get; set; }
            public int payout_foreign_exchange_rate { get; set; }
            public List<DisputeDto> disputes { get; set; }
        }
```

How do you suggest representing this Entity in db?

As you see i have three `List` objects in my Root object and this it what make it a little but complicated to decide how to save it.

- We are not gonna use EntityFramework or NHibernate.

Comment: You mean you need  a data-model?

Comment: Why not use EntityModel?  This seems like the exact type of situation it was created for.

Comment: I know and i would use something like NHibernate if i could.
This is an old code i can`t change so much but i am trying to do the best i can. If you have an idea how to design it i will be glad to hear.
We use this information only for customer support. It is not a big part of our application.

Comment: Nhibernate works well when you are not using a recent version SQL server, otherwise I would look into using entity framework

Comment: I am looking for something othee than entityframework..